# If my WordPress post does not contain a featured image, the caption still appears but it contains the post excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

The news articles on my site contain a featured image which has a caption attached.

My problem is that when an article does not contain a featured image the caption still appears, and it contains the excerpt of the news article.

```
<div class="single-img-container">
  <?php 
    the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class'=>"img-responsive single-news-img"));
    echo '<div class="news-img-caption">'.get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt.'</div>'; 
  ?>
</div>
```

My ideal result would be that if no featured image is included, the caption div will not appear.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap that whole thing in a condition that nothing is printed out if the SRC is empty?

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use the 'has_post_thumbnail()' conditional to make sure the post/page has a featured image.  the code below will output the markup '...' only if a featured image exists.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<div class="single-img-container">
  <?php 
    the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class'=>"img-responsive single-news-img"));
    echo '<div class="news-img-caption">'.get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt.'</div>'; 
  ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail